# Passing other Cython-bound objects to methods on a Cython-bound object

Tags: python, c, cython

I've got a Cython class which binds to a C library, called `TagDetector`, and I've got another class `TagFamily`, which I want to be able to instantiate and pass with a message as such:

```
td = TagDetector()
td.add_family(TagFamily('tag16h5'))
```

TagFamily, internally, uses struct creation functions from the C library to set a pointer variable `self._tag_family`.
How can I make a method on `TagDetector` which I can pass a `TagFamily` to, which then extracts the `_tag_family` stuct and does stuff with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to declare the type of the argument as being of the type `TagFamily`, then you can access all attributes. Additionally you probably also want to prevent the user from passing `None` which can be done by adding `not None`. Note that the `TagFamily` instance in your example will be deconstructed after the call to `add_family`. As your c struct should then be deleted, too, you need to prevent this if you want to continue using the c struct after the end of add_family. From your example I guess that your `TagDetector` will hold a list of families, if this is true the easiest way to avoid these memory management problems is to give `TagDetector` a Python list that holds references to all tag families in the `TagDetector`. Example:

```
cdef class TagDetector:
    cdef list families

    def __init__(self):
        self.families = []

    def add_family(self, TagFamily family not None):
        # prevent family from being deconstructed after add_family returns
        self.families.append(family)
        my_c_function(family._tag_family)
```